# Zendframework 3 Tutorial PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of XXXXXXbytes exhausted

Tags: php, fatal-error, zend-db, zend-framework3

we tried to implement the zf3 tutorial:

https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/

This worked fine until we tried to put a new indexAction() into our RequestTable:

```
return new ViewModel([
    'albums' => $this->table->fetchAll(),
]);`
```

The fetchAll() has the following definition:

```
public function fetchAll()
{
   return $this->tableGateway->select();
}
```

By doing so, the website turns white and does not throw any own, zendframework-related error. Only the apache server displays:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 66719744 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

Our module.config.php is structured as follows:

```
namespace Request;


use Request\Controller\RequestController;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;

return [
    'dependencies' => [
        'factories' => [
            AdapterInterface::class => AdapterServiceFactory::class,
            ],
        ],

    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'request' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/request[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => RequestController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

If we call

```
 public function fetchAll()
 {
     return $this->tableGateway->getTable();
 }
```

instead, then the website **does not** turn white and **no** errors are logged in apache. Just nothing happens.

Our global.php, which should contain the information relevant for the database, looks as follows:

```
return [
    'db' => [
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'database'    => 'test_db',
        'username'  => 'db_tester',
        'password' => 'XXXXXX',
    ],
];
```

This is our RequestTable.php:

```
namespace Request\Model;

use RuntimeException;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGatewayInterface;

class RequestTable
{
    private $tableGateway;

    /**
     * RequestTable constructor.
     * @param TableGatewayInterface $tableGateway
     */
    public function __construct(TableGatewayInterface $tableGateway)
    {
       $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        return $this->tableGateway->select();
    }
```

And this is the request.php:

```
namespace Request\Model;

class Request{

    public $request_id;
    public $email;
    public $type;

    public function exchangeArray(array $data)
    {
        $this->request_id     = !empty($data['request_id']) ? $data['request_id'] : null;
        $this->email          = !empty($data['email']) ? $data['email'] : null;
        $this->type           = !empty($data['type']) ? $data['type'] : null;
    }


}
```

Our Module.php looks as follows:

```
namespace Request;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }


    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                Model\RequestTable::class => function($container) {
                    $tableGateway = $container->get(Model\RequestTableGateway::class);
                    return new Model\RequestTable($tableGateway);
                },
                Model\RequestTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
                    $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\Request());
                    return new TableGateway('request', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                Controller\RequestController::class => function($container) {
                    return new Controller\RequestController(
                        $container->get(Model\RequestTable::class)
                    );
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Now we get the following failure message, after adding:

```
var_dump(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS))
```

Error message:

```
array(10) { [0]=> array(3) { ["file"]=> string(90) "/var/www/heinrich.jens.vawi.de/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php" ["line"]=> int(505) ["function"]=> string(7) "include" } [1]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(74) "/var/www/heinrich.jens.vawi.de/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php" ["line"]=> int(207) ["function"]=> string(6) "render" ["class"]=> string(30) "Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" } [2]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(74) "/var/www/heinrich.jens.vawi.de/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php" ["line"]=> int(236) ["function"]=> string(6) "render" ["class"]=> string(14) "Zend\View\View" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" } [3]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(74) "/var/www/heinrich.jens.vawi.de/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php" ["line"]=> int(200) ["function"]=> string(14) "renderChildren" ["class"]=> string(14) "Zend\View\View" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" } [4]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(103) "/var/www/heinrich.jens.vawi.de/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php" ["line"]=> int(105) ["function"]=> string(6) "render" ["class"]=> string(14) "Zend\View\View" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" } [5]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(90) "/var/www/heinrich.jens.vawi.de/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php" ["line"]=> int(322) ["function"]=> string(6) "render" ["class"]=> string(43) "Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" } [6]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(90) "/var/www/heinrich.jens.vawi.de/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php" ["line"]=> int(171) ["function"]=> string(16) "triggerListeners" ["class"]=> string(30) "Zend\EventManager\EventManager" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" } [7]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(80) "/var/www/heinrich.jens.vawi.de/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php" ["line"]=> int(367) ["function"]=> string(12) "triggerEvent" ["class"]=> string(30) "Zend\EventManager\EventManager" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" } [8]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(80) "/var/www/heinrich.jens.vawi.de/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php" ["line"]=> int(348) ["function"]=> string(15) "completeRequest" ["class"]=> string(20) "Zend\Mvc\Application" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" } [9]=> array(5) { ["file"]=> string(47) "/var/www/heinrich.jens.vawi.de/public/index.php" ["line"]=> int(62) ["function"]=> string(3) "run" ["class"]=> string(20) "Zend\Mvc\Application" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" } }
```

All we did was following the Tutorial posted above... 
No idea though what this error message means <.< 
Still looking for any advice out there!!!

Heinrich

Comment: have you tried returning `return new ViewModel(['text' => 'hello world']);` to see if it works like that ?

Comment: Yup that's working fine!

Comment: Now i'm wondering where is your controller factory where you inject your table. Where is your Table factory too ? Maybe problems in here. Otherwise try to return a text in your fetchAll() method

Comment: Posting a text does not work.

Comment: Updated the question...

Comment: Posted a current error message

Comment: Hmm.. is it database or zf, which one is crashing? try to fetch all and dont send them to view model. lets see database can server all data. maybe you have an endless loop in view.

Comment: Yup, that's what happened. Fixed it now.